# Can I take two different column values of same table and connect with different one column values from another table by using LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, datagridview

I have a sample shipment company database that has many tables. Some of these are "Shipments", "ShipmentDetails", and "Customers" tables. "Customers" table keeps informations of company's customers; "Shipments" table keeps general informations and shipment ID of every shipment of company and "ShipmentDetails" keeps specific informations of these shipments such as volume, weight, cost, distance etc.

One of the my application's forms, users can query their shipment informations(&status) by using their own and their receivers personal identification numbers. I wrote the following query to make it.

```
> var q = from shipments in model.Shipments
>                     join shipmentdetails in model.ShipmentDetails on shipments.ID equals shipmentdetails.ShipmentID
>                     where shipments.SenderTCID == maskedTextBox1.Text && shipments.ReceiverTCID == maskedTextBox2.Text
>                     select new
>                     {
>                         shipments.ID,
>                         shipments.Status,
>                         shipments.SenderTCID,
>                         shipments.ReceiverTCID,
>                         shipments.ReceivingDate,
>                         shipments.DeliveryDate,
>                         shipmentdetails.Weight,
>                         shipmentdetails.Volume,
>                         shipmentdetails.Type,
>                         shipmentdetails.Cost,
>                         shipmentdetails.Distance,
>                     };
>             dataGridView1.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

Later, I wanted to add my datagridview these customers names according to SenderID and ReceiverID values in queried cargo informations. I want to show as `" '150'(ShipmentID) - 'Delivered'(Status) - 123456789 (SenderID) - Michael (Sender Name) - 123456781(ReceiverID) - John (Receiver Name) - .... ".`

Can I alter the code in this way without any change in my tables? (without adding SenderName and ReceiverName values to "Shipments" table).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    **Yes You Can do this by Add two more field in your Shipments model.
    SenderName ,ReceiverName**

    if Your Model.Shipments have not SenderName and ReceiverName in Database,
    Than You Need to Create Class for Shipment Reference 
    Ex 


    public class ShipmentView
{
public int Id{get;set;}
public bool Status{get;set;}
public double Cost{get;set;}
public string Type{get;set;}
public string ReceiverName{get;set;}
public string SenderName{get;set;}
}




        select new ShipmentView()
        >                     {
        >                        Id = shipments.ID,
        >                        Status = shipments.Status,
        >                        SenderTCID = shipments.SenderTCID,
                                 SenderName = (from sendername in model.Sender where sendername.SenderId == shipments.SenderId select sendername).single().SenderName, 
        ReceiverName = (from receivername in model.Receiver where receivername.ReceiverId == shipments.ReceiverId select receivername).single().ReceieverName, 
        >                         shipments.ReceiverTCID,
        >                         shipments.ReceivingDate,
        >                         shipments.DeliveryDate,
        >                         shipmentdetails.Weight,
        >                         shipmentdetails.Volume,
        >                         shipmentdetails.Type,
        >                         shipmentdetails.Cost,
        >                         shipmentdetails.Distance,
        >                     };
```

Comment: I didn't need to create class for reference. However, I used your query and assignment inside of SenderName two times for SenderName and ReceiverName variables those I write in my main "select new {}" block. So It worked nice. Thanks for your help mate!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about where do you store the sender/receiver names so I did create the customer table (class object) and I put two members where one is the receiver and the other is the sender.

Next, to keep your top query intact as is, you can add member declaration in your select new anonymous type {...} and then, in the corresponding properties (receiver name, sender name), you can do a sub-select to retrieve the name according to the id. Since the var will hold a IEnumerable, you can do a q1.First() do retrieve the first element.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestConsole
{
   public class StackOverflow
   {

      public void test()
      {
         int senderid = 123456789;
         int receiverid = 123456781;

         Custommer[] cust = new Custommer[]
         {
            new Custommer()
            {
                ID = 123456789,
                Name = "John_Sender"
            },
            new Custommer()
            {
                ID = 123456781,
                Name = "Bob_Receiver"
            }
         };

         Shipments[] shipments = new Shipments[]
         {
            new Shipments()
            {
                ID = 150,
                SenderID = 123456789,
                ReceiverID = 123456781,
                ReceivingDate = new DateTime(2016, 09, 01),
                DeliveryDate = new DateTime(2016, 09, 02),
                Status = "Delivered"
            },
         };

         ShipmentDetail[] shipmentdetails = new ShipmentDetail[]
         {
            new ShipmentDetail()
            {
                ShipmentID = 150,
                Weight = 25.00,
                Volume = 25.00,
                Type = "Whatever",
                Cost = 25.00,
                Distance = 25.00
            },
         };

        var q1 = from _shipment in shipments
                join _shipmentdetail in shipmentdetails on _shipment.ID equals _shipmentdetail.ShipmentID
                where _shipment.SenderID == senderid && _shipment.ReceiverID == receiverid
                select new
                {
                    ShipmentID = _shipment.ID,
                    Status = _shipment.Status,
                    SenderID = _shipment.SenderID,
                    SenderName = cust.Where(s => s.ID == _shipment.SenderID).Select(s => s.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                    ReceiverID = _shipment.ReceiverID,
                    ReceiverName = cust.Where(s => s.ID == _shipment.ReceiverID).Select(s => s.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                };
        var q2 = q1.First();

        Console.WriteLine
        (
            "Shipment Id  = " + q2.ShipmentID.ToString() + "\n" +
            "Status = " + q2.Status + "\n" +
            "Sender ID = " + q2.SenderID + "\n" +
            "SenderName = " + q2.SenderName + "\n" +
            "Receiver ID = " + q2.ReceiverID + "\n" +
            "Receiver Name = " + q2.ReceiverName
        );
    }

    public class Custommer
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
    }

    public class Shipments
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Status;
        public int SenderID;
        public int ReceiverID;
        public DateTime ReceivingDate;
        public DateTime DeliveryDate;
    }

    public class ShipmentDetail
    {
        public int ShipmentID;
        public double Weight;
        public double Volume;
        public string Type;
        public double Cost;
        public double Distance;
    }
  }
}
```

[Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wcxD.png)